# Why is changing values in a column of a pandas data frame fast in one case and slow in another one?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy

I have two pieces of code that seem to do the same thing but one is almost a thousand times faster than the other one.

This is the first piece:

```
t1 = time.time()
df[new_col] = np.where(df[col] < j, val_1, val_2)
t2 = time.time()
ts.append(t2 - t1)
```

In `ts` I have values like:

```
0.0007321834564208984, 0.0002918243408203125, 0.0002799034118652344
```

In contrast, this part of the code:

```
t1 = time.time()
df['new_col'] = np.where((df[col] >= i1) & (df[col] < i2), val, df.new_col)
t2 = time.time()
ts.append(t2 - t1)
```

Creates `ts` populated with the values like:

```
0.11008906364440918, 0.09556794166564941, 0.08580684661865234
```

I cannot figure out what the essential difference is between the first and second assignments.

In both cases `df` should be the same.

**ADDED**

It turned out that the essential difference was not in the place where I was looking. In the fast version of the code I had:

```
df = inp_df.copy()
```

in the beginning of the class method (where `inp_df` was the input data frame of the method). In the slow version, I was operating directly on the input data frame. It became fast after copying the input data frame and operating on it.

Comment: Try to pre-compute the where condition and only time the call to np.where and the assignment to df[new_col]. What do you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Assignment is not the bottleneck

Assigning values to Pandas series is cheap, especially if you are assigning via regular objects such as `pd.Series`, `np.ndarray` or `list`.

#### Broadcasting is even cheaper

Note [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) is extremely cheap, i.e. when you are setting scalar values such as `val_1` and `val_2` in the first example.

Your second example has a series assignment for the case where your condition is not met. This is relatively expensive.

#### Calculations are relatively expensive

On the other hand, the *calculations* you perform are relatively expensive.

In the first example, you have one calculation:

```
df[col] < j
```

In the second example, you have at least three calculations:

```
a = df[col] >= i1
b = df[col] < i2
a & b
```

Therefore, you can and should expect the second version to be more expensive.

#### Use `timeit`

It's good practice to use the `timeit` module for reliable performance timings. The *reproducible* example below shows a smaller performance differential than what you claim:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.random(10**7)})

j = 0.5
i1, i2 = 0.25, 0.75

%timeit np.where(df['A'] < j, 1, 2)                             # 85.5 ms per loop
%timeit np.where((df['A'] >= i1) & (df['A'] < i2), 1, df['A'])  # 161 ms per loop
```

One calculation is cheaper than 3 calculations:

```
%timeit df['A'] < j                                             # 14.8 ms per loop
%timeit (df['A'] >= i1) & (df['A'] < i2)                        # 65.6 ms per loop
```

Broadcasting via scalar values is cheaper than assigning series:

```
%timeit np.where(df['A'] < j, 1, df['A'])                       # 113 ms per loop
%timeit np.where((df['A'] >= i1) & (df['A'] < i2), 1, 2)        # 146 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

First time you use only one condition so it should be faster than you do check  the two conditions. Simple example use ipython:

```
In [3]: %timeit 1 < 2                                                                                                                                         
20.4 ns ± 0.434 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit 1 >= 0 & 1 < 2                                                                                                                                
37 ns ± 1.37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```